# Optimal Bandwidth Selection for Propensity Score Matching in Stata

Tags: cross-validation, stata, matching, propensity-scores, difference-in-difference

currently I am performing a DID ATT estimation with propensity score matching and I want to present estimates for NN-matching with 1 and 2 neighbors as well as kernel(gaussian)-matching with an optimal bandwidth selection. I am bound to use Stata.

I know that there are several methods to use to choose an optimal kernel, some performing better, some less. As the propensity score densities are far from being normal distributed I do not want to use Silvermans rule of thumb and crossed the method of leave-one-out cross validation.

Is there a way I can perform this in Stata? I am not really an expert in setting up ado programs and so far see now way how to minimize the loocv function with respect to h. Is there anyone with experience in this?

Cheers!